# Find the sum of the geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, geometric-progressions

$$1+ \frac12 + \frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}$$

To find the sum of the equation you have to find $n$, the number of terms in the geometric sequence and I don't know how...

The answer in the text book is $2-\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: Well prove the text book answer via induction.

Comment: This was asked earlier today and closed as a duplicate of another question.  So this is a dupe of a dupe.

Comment: Do you know anything about mathematical induction?

Comment: @amWhy Then let us close it.

Comment: @Simple Trying to find it while others rush to answer it anyway!

Comment: @amWhy (>.<) Sorry, but I posted a good enough answer while "rushing", so made it community :D.  Lol.

Comment: Alternatively we can give a record number of answers.

Comment: The question as stated is absurd and **none** of the proposed answers address that absurdity (although SBA's answer is better than the rest). The question (not the title) asks how to find $n$ given $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + \ldots + 1/2^n$.

Comment: If you divide all terms by $2$, this has the same effect as dropping the first term and adding a new one $1/2^{n+1}$. Then it suffices to solve the equation $S/2=S-1+1/2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Any way, its repetitive questions and answers like shown here that provide many users here their only opportunity to gain rep, because they don't know enough to answer better and/or more legit questions.  So they race for the rep.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, your sum will be $2$ minus a small square or rectangle in the corner.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $$s_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac 1{2^k}=1+\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+\cdots+\frac 1{2^n}$$
Multiplying both sides by $2$ gives$$2s_n=2+1+\frac 12+\cdots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}$$
Subtracting, we have$$s_n=2-\frac 1{2^n}$$

Note that this trick can be used on *most* simple geometric sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S = 1+ \frac12 + \frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}$.  Then $2S = 2 + 1 + \frac12 + \frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n - 1}}$.  Subtract the second equation from the first one to get
$$S = 2 - \frac1{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to *find* $n$, the question is requesting a formula that lets somebody plug in any arbitrary $n$ and tells her what that sum is.

One way to find that formula, without just looking at patterns and without anything fancy like an induction proof, is to subtract $1$ from the sum and manipulate as follows:
$$
S = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \\
S-1 = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} \\
S-1 = \sum_{(k-1) = 0}^{n-1} 2^{-((k-1)+1)} \\
S-1 = \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} 2^{-(m+1)} \\
S-1 = \frac12 \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} 2^{-m} \\
S-1 = \frac12 (S - 2^{-n})\\
\frac12 S - 1 = -\frac12  2^{-n}\\
S-2 = -2^{-n} \\
S = 2 - 2^{-n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $S_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i$. Then $S_n(x)-xS_n(x)=1-x^{n+1}$. Hence $S_n(x)=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. Thus $S_n(\frac{1}{2})=2-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Results from a well-known high-school formula:
$$1-x^{n}=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots x^{n-1})$$
which can be read as well:
$$1+x+x^2+\dots x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}-\frac{x^{n}}{1-x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$2=1+1=1+\frac12+\frac12=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac14=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac18=\\
1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^n}.$$